# How does the Spring forms .jsp tag library work?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

So I have a .jsp page which has a form on it, like this (naturally this is a massive simplification):

```
<form:form commandName="myCommand" method="post">
    <form:select path="values" class="select-tall" multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
        <option>first</option>
        <option>second</option>
        <option>third</option>
    </form:select>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
</form:form>
```

When the submit button is pressed, the form is submitted(somehow) and the `path=` attributes are used to bind the data inside the form elements to the properties of an instance of a plain old java object. I understand how this POJO is specified, and I understand how the POST request is routed to the correct controller, but I don't understand where or how the form values are mapped to the given POJO.

What I don't understand is:

- How does the spring tag library modify the form such that this binding takes place?
- How would one go about doing this in a manual or ad-hoc fashion(using a Javascript onSubmit() method, say)?

Essentially my question is: **How does the spring-form.tld tag library work?**

Any resources, or even a high-level explanation in your own words, would be extremely helpful.

I've implemented a work-around solution in the mean time (dynamically adding items to a hidden form element), but I feel like this is hack-y and the wrong solution.

Comment: Look into Spring's `FormTag` class implementation. Go down the source code rabbit hole.

Comment: I can't find the source. it's just a binary in a jar somewhere :(

Comment: You can find it online (on maven or github directly).

Comment: Here it is :) https://www.google.co.in/search?q=FormTag+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iApvVfPIMMmwuASP14GoCg